# PyArmor, "Too big code object, the limitation is 32768 bytes in trial version" error even the size of file is 30K

Tags: python, pyarmor

## problem

I want to obfuscate my Python script with PyArmor.
Originally its file size was 45 kilobytes and I got an error;

```
ERROR    Too big code object, the limitation is 32768 bytes in trial version
```

So I removed comments and blank lines, and the size became 30K. But I still got the same error. How can I fix?

By the way, I noticed PyArmor obfuscated some files whose size are larger than 32768 bytes. I also don't understand this.

## versions

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- PyArmor Trial Version 6.6.0

Comment: It is likely that the size is an estimate and is based on memory requirements rather than filesize. The intent of the limit is clear. It is not a promise to work with files of precisely 32768 bytes. It is a limit to stop you using the trial version for anything other than toy programs.

Answer (score 1):

If your file really has less than 32Kb, do the following: cut this file out of your current directory, and paste it in an empty folder, from there perform your processes with pyarmor and it will work normally. After generating the obsfuscated file you can place it in the directory with dependent folders (if necessary).